# json object data changes and sometimes there is no value

Tags: java, android, json, api

I am searching a database of items. And when I do a search in my android app and get json back it breaks if an item doesnt have a value for one of the objects.

For example if I have this data returned for an item:

name
ID
IBU
ABV

not every item has a value for each data point so if an item is missing IBU it just does not have that data point in the json for it and my code just stops. One of my queries breaks when I search and an item doesnt have ibu. So I tried putting a try next to it to make it ignore it if it didnt get anything. It still just stopped.

```
String beerId = "";
                    String beerName = "";
                    String beerDescription = "";;
                    String beerAbv = "";
                    String beerIbu = "";

                    //json.getJSONArray("data").length()

                    //get json items
                    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

                        try{
                            beerId = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                        }
                        finally{}

                        beerName = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                        beerDescription = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
                        beerAbv = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("abv");
                        try{
                            beerIbu = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("ibu");
                        }
                        finally{beerIbu = "";}
```

Comment: `try { beerIbu = xxx; } finally { beerIbu = ""; }` <-- `beerIbu` will _always_ have value `""` here

Comment: @fge so should I take the finally out? It says I have to have it. Also if I leave the finally empty it still doesn't work.

Comment: If they don't exist, then getting them and attempting to use them without checking if anything was returned isn't going to work. Don't do that.

Comment: I love being voted down for no reason....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to fix this is by creating a method (void) that does all the work then returns the answer you are looking for. I am working on a YouTube video to help better explain, but here is the code:

```
 String beerId = GetBeerDataFromJSON(0,"id");
 String beerName = GetBeerDataFromJSON(0,"name");
 String beerDescription = GetBeerDataFromJSON(0,"description");
 String beerAbv = GetBeerDataFromJSON(0,"abv");
 String beerIbu = GetBeerDataFromJSON(0,"ibu");
```

Then outside of that void (but in the same class) create the return method.

```
 private String GetBeerDataFromJSON(int position, String whatToGet) {
    String whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor = whatToGet;
    int whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData = position;

    String holder = "";


    try{
        holder = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData).getString(whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        holder = "";
    }



    return holder;
}
```

There is a more efficient way to write this code. In my video I will explain more. But this will work for now.